# simulate mac dock mouse over animation

Tags: animation, qml

I would like to try make a Dock app using QML (QtQuick) that emulates the animation of the MacOSX dock.

My intention is to make this a Desktop app, and use Mouse Area to detect mouse movements and create the "fish-eye" animation that the MacOSX dock is using.

I was thinking this would be possible using a QML ListView in horizontal mode (or vertical mode):

(see the expandingdelegates.qml:[Qt Reference Docs](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/declarative-modelviews-listview.html))

Just wanted to get some feedback from experts, can this be accomplished reasonably well with QML?  And where to start?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done very easily using qml. You need to study about :

- [List View](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-listview.html)

Learn how to create and use

- [List Models](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-listmodel.html)

Learn how to use one and to edit(delete,append) entries in a given model.

- [Mouse area](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-mousearea.html)

Learn how to use and about 'onEntered' and 'onExited' signals.

- [Scale](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-item.html#scale-prop) property
- [Behavior](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-behavior.html)

Learn how it can be used to provide animations for change in an elements properties.

I think if you are clear with using all the above, you will be able to clearly visualize how to achieve what you are thinking of doing.

Comment: Hi Amit: What about using a PathView: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-pathview.html

Comment: @user889329 With ListView you can have the view only linear (Horizontal/Vertical) in shape. But with PathView you can draw a custom path. That said, PathView is a little difficult to 'control' that is why I suggested for ListView which is comparatively easier to work with. If your requirements needs a path which is non-linear, PathView should be the way to go.

Comment: If I scale up one item, the other items in the list view do NOT automatically move to give room to the scaled item?  Any creative ideas how to solve this

Comment: I created it using only a Repeater element (to avoid built-in anchors of ListView), here's the video: [link]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQqFO4OkPO0&feature=youtu.be